# Get an asset's numerical position in an array in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I'm working with a list of assets, sorted alphabetically (through another method).
I would like to assign a value to the "position" key, which essentially just says where this particular asset appears in the ordered list of all assets.
Here is the code I'm working with now (:position left blank on purpose):

```
@active_resources.each do |asset|
  @asset_data[asset.id] = {
    :name => asset.name,
    :services => asset.active_services.collect{|service| 
      {:duration => service.duration, :name => service.name, :id => service.id}
    },
    :position => 
  }
end
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the list is already sorted (as you mention) and is implemented as an Array, you can use the [`Array::index`](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ref_c_array.html#Array.index) method to determine the numerical index of an item in the array.

If you are trying assign position values for the entire array, you could use something like:

```
@active_resources.each_with_index {|asset,idx|
    @asset_data[asset.id][:position] = idx
}
```

Comment: Would I be able to call that within my original method or should it be separate.
Thanks much.